# Evince PDF links disabling login ability to the followed URL

Tags: login, google-chrome, pdf, thunderbird, evince

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour when using corporate PDF documents and trying to follow links:

1. PDFs comes by email (using Thunderbird)
2. I open it directly from the attachment, with Evince
3. PDF has internal links that point me to our corporate website and this requires logging in to access content
4. Once clicked in PDF, it opens Google Chrome (my default browser) and ... once the user and password dialogue appears, the keyboard does not work. I cannot enter credentials.

If I right-click the link in PDF and copy the URL, then paste it in manually open chrome, it works without any problems.

I checked if downloading the document to the disk first, and then opening it locally (not directly from the Thunderbird) helps, but still, it does not: it opens a browser, asks to log in on my corporate website and login dialogue box won't let me type anything there.

BTW - the login type is an NT challenge/response type (the targer server is IIS), not the one embedded in the HTML page, it pops up.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't sound to me as a problem with Evince. What happens if you copy the link to e.g. a Libreoffice document and then click on it?

Comment: When you copy-paste, it works with whatever context, including Chrome but interestingly, if I just copy-paste into the browser that was opened when I clicked the link from the aforementioned PDF document, it does not work. I suspect, there is a kind of safety mechanism, that prevents me from entering credentials when clicked link via PDF, or at least it seems to be.

Comment: One more observation I just found: if my chrome is already started, and clicking the link in PDF creates a new tab, it works as expected. If chrome is opened as new (didn't run yet) then logging in is disabled. So it may be somehow related to the security I believe or at least the context the Evince starts the browser.

Comment: I did a short screencast presenting the problem: https://youtu.be/_tvj3HSbJrg